# PHP web Crawler prints twice extracted every statement

Tags: php

i been working on this web crawler. it works fine, except that it prints every single extracted statement twice.

i tried echoing at every loop but seems like it need some out of box perspective.

my code goes as:

```
<?php
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('https://www.uworld.com/Forum/topics.aspx?ForumID=1&gid=1');
    $elementCount=0;
    foreach($html->find('h3.h3-forum-title a') as $element) {
        $elementCount++;
    $element->href = "http://www.studentdoc.com/phpBB2/" . $element->href; 
    echo '<li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">';
    if($elementCount < 5 && $elementCount > 2 && rand(0,1) == 1) {
      echo '<span class="item_new">new</span>';
    }
    echo $element;
    echo '</li>';                           
    if($elementCount==12){
           break;
    }
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: You are not wrapping li with ul?

Comment: no, i m wrrapping. i just didnt add it in quesdtion

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because the element exists twice on the webpage. You have to narrow down your `find` parameters like this:

```
foreach($html->find('div.hidden-lg div div div div h3.h3-forum-title a') as $element) {
    // process the elements
}
```